# QPluginloader error: "Cannot load library: The specified module could not be found" unless the plugin is in the same folder as in .exe

Tags: c++, qt5

I am having a weird error while loading plugins using `QPluginloader`. I built 4 plugins in total all specified with `Q_PLUGIN_METADATA`, `Q_OBJECT` and `Q_INTERFACES`. I can see all the plugins are built properly and there are no missing .dlls (checked with Dependency walker). All these plugins are placed in separate "plugins" folder.

While loading, 2 plugins can be loaded without any problems. The other 2 plugins throw the error as mentioned in the title. If i copy the plugin dll and all its dependencies in the same folder with .exe, QPluginloader loads the plugin fine.

What am i missing?

I am using Qt 5.7 with VS 2015 on Win 10 x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While reading through [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order?redirectedfrom=MSDN#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications) i found out it is possible to modify the search order using `SetDllDirectoryA()` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectorya). It finally worked.

```
SetDllDirectoryA((LPCSTR) "path/to/plugin/folder");
```

Windows will now search for all the plugin dependencies in specified plugin directory which is otherwise never searched for.

More info about this issue can also be found [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/121547/qpluginloader-error-cannot-load-library-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-unless-the-plugin-is-in-the-same-folder-as-in-exe/2)